# Selenium tests, LiveServerTestCase, Django, and NoReverseMatch

Tags: django, testing, selenium

My test:

```
class BasicProfileTest(LiveServerTestCase):
fixtures = ['admin_user.json', 'gym.json', 'user_profile.json']

def setUp(self):
    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)

def tearDown(self):
    self.browser.quit()

def test_can_login_check_profile(self):
    self.browser.get(self.live_server_url + '/trackstats/index/')

    body = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
    self.assertIn('Track your workouts. See your progress. Share with friends.', body.text)

    username_field = self.browser.find_element_by_name('username')
    username_field.send_keys('bobo')

    password_field = self.browser.find_element_by_name('password')
    password_field.send_keys('.....')
    password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    profile_link = self.browser.find_element_by_link_text("bobo's profile")
    profile_link.click()

    body = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
    self.assertIn('Change Password', body.text)
```

When I run the test, it passes but it also throws a

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'user_profile_update' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

If I put a direct link to the user's profile in base.html:

```
/trackstats/profile/update/{{user.id}}
```

I do not get a reverse match exception.  But as soon as I replace it with

```
{% url user_profile_update user.id %}
```

it craps out with the NoReverMatch exception.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

update 1.  added urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', redirect_to, {'url': '/trackstats/index/'}),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'registration/login.html'}),
    (r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')), 
    url(r'^trackstats/index/', 'trackstats.views.index', name='index'),
    url(r'^trackstats/user_profile/create/', 'trackstats.views.user_profile_create', name='user_profile_create'),
    url(r'^trackstats/user_profile/update/(?P<object_id>\d{1,5})/', 'trackstats.views.user_profile_update', name='user_profile_update'),
    url(r'^trackstats/gym/create/', 'trackstats.views.gym_create', name='gym_create'),
    url(r'^trackstats/gym/update/(?P<object_id>\d{1,5})/', 'trackstats.views.gym_update', name='gym_update'),
    url(r'^trackstats/workout/create/', 'trackstats.views.workout_create', name='workout_create'),
    url(r'^trackstats/workout/update/(?P<object_id>\d{1,5})/', 'trackstats.views.workout_update', name='workout_update'),
    url(r'^trackstats/workout/assign/', 'trackstats.views.workout_assign', name='workout_assign'),

)
```

Comment: What is the associated line in `urls.py` containing 'user_profile_update'?

Comment: added full urls.py file.

Comment: The URL's all look like they make sense. I've updated my answer with more suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The exception says that there's no `user.id` being passed to the `reverse` function, it's just getting an empty string.

Can you look at a stack trace to see how the function is being called? (I might be being obtuse, but I can't see a call to `reverse` in your code above). You should be able to see where the empty string is coming from, and replace it with the `user.id` you want.

Also try looking at the user object you're passing to the template (the one you're using to test the `url` function above) - swap your test for `{{ user }}` just to be sure you're passing a valid user. If you're passing a valid user with a valid id then it maybe that there are duplicates in your url.conf (eg same view and same number of arguments). If this is the case then you may need to use [named url patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns).

UPDATE

Is it possible that the final assert statement in your test is being run before the page has loaded? Could you manually insert a 5 second wait after the `click()`? Have you run this through manually? Does logging in take you straight to a page with the text "change password" on it?

Comment: That's the weird thing. I'm _not_ calling reverse anywhere in the code. I'm opening up a firefox instance, going to a page, putting in a user/password, hitting return, and clicking on a link. The test _passes_. The page comes up in firefox without errors. But I get this crazy stacktrace, like you'd see if you passed nothing to {% url user_profile_update %}. It's baffling.

Comment: `reverse` will be called by the `{% url %}` tag but as Aidan has said, `user.id` appears to be an empty string in your template.  Perhaps you can output `{{ user.id }}` in a separate html element to check.